# What is better ram 800 and 800 as size of 800 each one or 1600 mhz on size 800?

Tags: memory

I have 8gb ram of 800mhz speed, i want to upgrade, what is better to have:

1- two 8gb ram of 800 mhz speed each(total 16 gb ram).

2- One 8gb ram of 1600 speed.

Comment: Are you sure the 1600 Mhz RAM will work on your motherboard?

Comment: Not really, how can i know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider here:

Firstly - will 1600MHz RAM even run in your motherboard?  Find your PC/Motherboard make and model and check the technical specifications to be sure.

I would suggest that you go with 2 * 800MHz.  You would be able to run your RAM in dual channel mode which will increase the performance of your memory and allow it to run at the full advertised speed.

On top of this, more RAM is (nearly) always better than faster RAM.  While you are looking to go to 16GB either way, I think that paying for 1600MHz RAM wouldn't give you a massive increase in performance.  IF your drive is a spinning drive instead of an SSD, your slowest computer component is the disk, not your RAM.  By increasing from 8GB to 16GB you can increase the amount of data stored in RAM for normal operation of your computer, reduce the amount of workload on your slower Disk and increase performance.. but by upping to 1600MHz RAM, you will pay more and see very little (if any) speed increase over installing a second stick of 800MHz.

It is perfectly fine to mix the two speeds, however, the 1600MHz RAM will "slow down" to match the 800MHz.  RAM (like network connections) will always work at the highest common denominator (800&1600=800, 1333&1600=1333, 800&800=800). This is a good idea if you are then planning to replace the other stick at a later date and move to 2*8*1600, but if you aren't, its not worth the money.  If you already have a stick of 8GB 800MHz, why bother upping it to 1600 16GB when you can still run 16GB for less by adding just a second 8GB?

Comment: Thank you so mach, 1- i have SSD. 2- my motherboard support 1600hz. 3- The difference between 800 and 1600MHZ is only 10$. Another question, did its ok to use 8 gb of 800mhz  with 8g 1600 mhz?

Comment: It is perfectly fine to mix the two, however - the 1600MHz RAM will "slow down" to match the 800MHz.  RAM (like network connections) will always work at the highest common denominator (800&1600=800, 1333&1600=1333, 800&800=800).  This is a good idea if you are then planning to replace the other stick at a later date and move to 2*8*1600, but if you aren't, its not worth the money

Comment: I don't agree with this answer at all. Unless OP is using really high memory usage programs to warrant needing over 8GB of RAM, 16GB of RAM @ 800MHZ is no where near on the performance level of 8GB of 1600MHZ RAM (http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/memory-bandwidth-latency-gaming,3409-10.html). Dual channel is hardly a factor in the decision. In a equal enviroment where one setup is one stick of 16GB @ 1600MHZ and one is two sticks of 8GB @ 1600MHZ, there is a mere 1-3% performance difference (SOURCE: http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/PARALLEL-PROCESSING,1705-15.html). I hope OP reads this.